# How Can I Flatten This List with Inner List of Lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the following `List`

```
lis =
{
  {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}}, {3, 2, 7}, 
  {{3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}
}
```

I would like to get this `List`:

```
{
  {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7}, 
  {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}
}.
```

`Flatten` is not doing it for me. Note that the actual List is huge and the List of Lists contained in this list can have variable lengths as in the example above one contains 3 inner list the other contains 4.

Comment: Are your lists only this deep or do you have additional or arbitrary layers of lists?

Comment: A simple and straightforward solution would be `lis //. {h___, {x__List}, t___} :> {h, x, t}`, but since your lists are huge, it'll be inefficient.

Comment: @rm-rf, the lists are only this deep.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Starting with (notice lists of length 1, 2, 3, and 4):

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 3}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7}, {6, 2, 1}}, {3, 2, 7},
       {{3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8, 0}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4}};
```

You could simply do:

```
Level[lis, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7},
>  {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8, 0}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4}}
> ```

This assumes that the elements of your sub-lists are atomic, i.e. `Depth` 1, such as head `Integer`, `Read`, `String`, etc.

If your elements are not atomic then a different method will be needed but I will need to better understand the possible forms of your data structure.  For example could you ever have something like `{6, {2, 3}, 1}` in your list, and what should be done with it?

One option is `Cases` with a pattern for objects that are not to be flattened:

```
Cases[lis, {Except[_List] ..}, -2]
```

Another is a recursive function similar to what rm-rf shows (but extensible to more deeply nested expressions).

Comment: thanks. Your method is generally faster.

Comment: @RunnyKine Depending on the actual structure of your data there are other options and considerations, e.g. `Level[lis, {-2}]` should be fastest/best if the elements of your sublists are atomic.  I've been distracted by another question but I'll come back to this one.  In the mean time can you tell what your actual data looks like?

Comment: The actual data looks like I described above and just like your example shows except that every list is of length three except the list of lists that can have variable lengths (still the inner lists are of length 3) like the list with 4 elements and that with 3 elements in my example. Your answer definitely solves the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another alternative which should be faster than using `?MatrixQ` and `Sequence@@` for large lists.

```
Block[{f},
     f[{x__List}] := x;
     f[x_] := x;
     f /@ list
]
```

### Timings:

#### Large list with relatively few sublists of array depth 2

```
list = With[{r := RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, 
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r, r}], {1000}] ~Join~
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r}], {1000000}]];

AbsoluteTiming[out1 = list /. x_?MatrixQ :> Sequence @@ x;] (* Verbeia *)
(* {4.213474, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
    out2 = Block[{f},
        f[{x__List}] := x;
        f[x_] := x;
        f /@ list
    ];
] (* rm -rf *)
(* {0.818107, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[out3 = Cases[list, {__Integer}, -2];] (* Mr.Wizard *)
(* {0.884933, Null} *)

out3 == out2 == out3
(* True *)
```

#### Large list with same number of sublists of depth 1 and 2.

```
list = With[{r := RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, 
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r, r}], {1000000}] ~Join~
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r}], {1000000}]
];
```

The timings are (in the same order)

```
(* {38.116132, 17.419978, 6.152006} *)
```

#### Large list with relatively few sublists of array depth 1

```
list = With[{r := RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, 
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r, r}], {10000000}] ~Join~
    Table[RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {r}], {1000}]
];
```

Timings are

```
(* {14.443210, 6.843764, 4.206555 *)
```

So it seems that the size and structure of the list also matters for the timings, with mine tending to be faster when there are relatively few sublists of depth 2 (since the main workhorse is just `f[x_] := x`) and Mr.Wizard's faster when the situation is the opposite. However, Mr.Wizard's is in general a much faster alternative and applicable to lists of arbitrary depth.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely fast.

Comment: Maybe I read too much into the question but this doesn't work as I expect or a deeper expression, e.g. `RandomChoice[lis, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 7}, 10]`.  If I apply the function repeatedly so as to get the expected result it takes longer than `Cases`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See my comment to the OP under the question and their response

Comment: Oh.  Well, aren't you the one that contends that comments are not content? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's why I posted an answer and left the room heater solution as a comment :) I meant the _other_ comment where the OP clarifies the depth of the lists...

Comment: Could you check the timings I added to my post in a newer version?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Pls see my update (more or less confirms your findings). It seems like mine is much faster when the ratio of depth2 sublists vs depth1 sublists is small.

Comment: I tried to repeat your timings and I get different results on different runs (for the same data).  I think it's because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling).  After many runs it slows down.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't know about that, and unfortunately, won't have time to investigate today either. I hadn't noticed this issue, but if you can reproduce it and others can too, perhaps it might be worth a question (you might also want to make sure that there aren't other things going on in your machine when you test)

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
lis /. a_?MatrixQ :> Sequence @@ a
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7}, {3,
>   3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}}
> ```

This is a bit of a hack, but if you had unknown depth of nesting, you could try something like:

```
lis2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {{{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}}}, {3,
    2, 7}, {{3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}}

Last@DeleteCases[
  FixedPointList[# /. a_?MatrixQ :> Sequence @@ a &, lis2], _?VectorQ]
```

The reason I do it this way instead of using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) is that the final desired outcome is itself a matrix, and is matched by the rule. So the end point is a `Sequence` of vectors. You want to get to that point, eliminate those vectors from the results, and then pick whatever was the result of the `FixedPointList` before that happened. You can see this by just using `FixedPointList`, which gives the following output:

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {{{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}}}, {3, 2, 
   7}, {{3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4,
    3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}}, {3,
    2, 7}, {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 
   4, 3}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3,
    2, 7}, {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 
   4, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 
  2, 7}, {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4,
   3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Comment: Nice, you could also add `Sequence -> List` at the end, just in case the original list has no matrix-lists.

Comment: Nice one. +1. Thanks, I like the elegance of your answers.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another one (since I don't see `Replace` mentioned):

```
Replace[lis, {l__List} -> l, {1}]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7}, 
    {3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}} *)
```

On my machine this is about three times faster than @rm's solution for his first dataset and a little bit faster for the second.  `Replace` can be surprising ;-)  I learned about its speed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/695132).

Comment: Nice. +1 for the `Replace` tip.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
Partition[Flatten[lis], 3]
```

Comment: The question states: "Note that the actual List is huge and the List of Lists contained in this list can have variable lengths."

Comment: ok, I read the question as the "list of lists" could have variable lengths as opposed to the lists within the "list of lists". The description isn't not totally unclear to me still.

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[lis, __?VectorQ, -2]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7}, {3,
>   3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution

```
flatten[l_List] := Block[{aux}, aux[x_List] := x //. List[a__List] :> Sequence@a; aux /@ l]
```

Comment: I gave a solution based on `//.` in the comments, but didn't post it because the OP mentioned that their lists are huge and `//.` will be terribly slow

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}}, {3, 2, 7},
   {{3, 3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}};

FlattenAt[list, Position[list, _?MatrixQ]]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 3}, {6, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 7}, {3,
3, 5}, {7, 7, 8}, {9, 4, 2}, {9, 0, 0}, {8, 5, 4}, {7, 4, 3}}