# What is the best way to flatten a linked list with lists as values?

Tags: list-manipulation

By following the advice on [this site](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node525.html) I have ended up with a linked list like the following:

```
acc = {{1, 2}, {{2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {{4, 5}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}}};
```

This was obtained by accumulating the values `{i,j}` during a recursion.  What is the most efficient way to flatten the list to get the following:

```
flatAcc = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}
```

Right now I am cheating by doing the following:

```
flatAcc = Partition[Flatten[acc], 2];
```

But I feel that Mathematica must have a better paradigm for this task.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See the section "Generalize linked lists" in the answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474. It has an example of flattening the list as well, which will work if the elements are lists.

Comment: In test I made a couple years ago, your 'cheat' was the fastest method I found. I recommend sticking with it.

Comment: @m_goldberg if lists have different lengths then it will not work.

Comment: @Algohi. Flattening a linked list of pairs or triples comes up all the time in code involving 2D and 3D geometry. Flattening and re-partitioning is the best way I know to handle this common problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg Please see the **Performance** section of my answer.  Things appear to have changed.

Comment: Closely related: [(20319)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20319/121)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your method is good but I also would suggest the following:

```
Cases[acc, {x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ} :> {x, y}, -1]
```

or easier:

```
Cases[acc, {__}, {-2}]                (*@ Alexey Popkov*)
```

This would be better but if you don't have empty list at the end.

```
Level[acc, {-2}]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {}}*)
```

in this case you may delete the empty list using any method. for example :

```
Most@Level[acc, {-2}]

(*{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}*)
```

Comment: (+1) Actually the replacement in your `Cases` code isn't needed because it does not change anything. Assuming that all the numbers are `AtomQ`, `Cases[acc, {__}, {-2}]` gives the same result with much better performance. If the numbers may not be atomic, `Cases[acc, {__?NumberQ}, -2]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov great approach. I hope you don't mind if I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 14):

### A different head

You can avoid the problem from the outset by using a different head for your linked "list" e.g. [`AngleBracket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AngleBracket.html):

```
flatAcc = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}

x = Fold[〈#2, #〉 &, 〈〉, Reverse @ flatAcc]
```

> ```
> 〈{1,2}, 〈{2,3}, 〈{3,4}, 〈{4,5}, 〈{5,6}, 〈〉〉〉〉〉〉
> ```

Now `Flatten` can be used:

```
Flatten[x, ∞, AngleBracket]
```

> ```
> 〈{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}〉
> ```

- You can [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) `List` as needed at this point.
- There is nothing special about `AngleBracket`; I just used it because it looks rather nice.

### `Bag` functionality

One may use the undocumented [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/618728)  functionality in place of linked lists in many applications.

```
bag = Internal`Bag[];                          (* create bag *)

Scan[Internal`StuffBag[bag, #] &, flatAcc];    (* incrementally fill bag *)

Internal`BagPart[bag, All]                     (* get flat bag contents *)
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}
> ```

### Performance

[m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) asserted that a `Flatten` and `Partition` is the fastest method available.  This is not borne out in my testing.

I could not include Algohi's `Level` method as *Mathematica* 10.0.1 crashed when the linked list grew longer.

```
(* timing function *)
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

(* random pairs common to all tests *)
rand = RandomInteger[99, {2000000, 2}];

(* build each "linked list" or equivalent *)
linked = Fold[List, rand];
linked2 = Fold[AngleBracket, rand];
bag = Internal`Bag[rand];

(* timings *)
Flatten[linked] ~Partition~ 2      // timeAvg
Flatten[linked2, ∞, AngleBracket]  // timeAvg
Internal`BagPart[bag, All]         // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 1.529
>
> 0.131
>
> 0.0187
> ```

We see that in this test using `AngleBracket` and `Flatten` alone is more than an order of magnitude faster than using `Flatten` and `Partition`, and the `Bag` method is nearly two orders of magnitude faster than the original.

Notes:

- Lest it confuse anyone the two-argument from of `Fold` is used; see: [Shorter syntax for Fold and FoldList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)
- The linked list format used is different as I used e.g. bare `List` rather than `{#2, #} &` but I tried both ways and the timings were unaffected.

---

### Addendum

Algohi wrote that I should provide a method to convert the OP's `acc` format to another head.  I agree.

```
rule = {a_, b_} :> 〈a, b /. rule〉;

acc /. rule
```

> ```
> 〈{1,2}, 〈{2,3}, 〈{3,4}, 〈{4,5}, 〈{5,6}, {}〉〉〉〉〉
> ```

This misses `{}` but that can be dropped later with `Most`.  A more general replacement function:

```
convert[_[a_, b_], h_] := h[a, convert[b, h]]
convert[_[], h_] := h[]
```

Now:

```
convert[〈{1,2}, 〈{2,3}, 〈{3,4}, 〈{4,5}, 〈{5,6}, {}〉〉〉〉〉, foo]
```

> ```
> foo[{1, 2}, foo[{2, 3}, foo[{3, 4}, foo[{4, 5}, foo[{5, 6}, foo[]]]]]]
> ```

It would of course be more efficient to construct the linked "list" in this format to begin with.

Comment: Doesn't function, isn't obvious and your `flatAcc` isn't even defined.

Comment: @eldo LOL -- anything else? :o)  `flatAcc` is defined in the question but I'll include it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I rather flatly beg your pardon :)

Comment: What if your list is {{1, 2}, {{2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {{4, 5}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}}}? how to use Flatten in this case? I tried to replace List to AngleBracket but it did not work.

Comment: @Algohi My suggestion is to avoid creating that expression in the first place.  Your solution seems like a good one if one already has that expression, unless it is deep enough to crash *Mathematica* (bug).

Comment: it is actually great idea. I think you should look at a method to convert acc in OP to x in your answer :)

Comment: @Algohi Appended.

Comment: +1 Your answer is very enlightening. The test I referred to in my comment to the question only looked at ways of flattening the usual linked lists. `Flatten` and `Partition` are still good for that. I didn't think to use a bag because I didn't know that bags existed in _Mathematica_. I would have happily used  your `AngleBracket` idea had I been clever enough to think of it.

Comment: What font do you use? The `AngelBracket` simply [doesn't display correctly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tmfw6.jpg) in my browser.

Comment: @xzczd Ugg.  I thought it was a common (unicode) character.  If I am using the Element Inspector of my browser correctly the font is specified as: `font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono',Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;`.  Since I don't have Droid Sans Mono installed but I do have Consolas I believe it should be using the latter.  However I quick check indicates that Consolas does not include these glyphs therefore it must be drawing on a different source.  (continued)

Comment: I should probably avoid using these characters here; nevertheless I shall try to figure out where the actual glyphs are being drawn from.  Incidentally do these other characters display as intended?: `∞ ⌊ ⌋ ⌈ ⌉ ⋃ ⋂` (Infinity, left-floor, right-floor, left-ceiling, right-ceiling, union, intersection.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah, they all [display as intended](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2IgJg.jpg).

Answer (score 8):

A generalization

```
acc = {{a, b, c}, {{2}, {{"a", 4}, {{4, 5}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}}};

Cases[acc, {x__?AtomQ} :> {x}, -1]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {2}, {"a", 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

**Nest** combined with **FlattenAt** / **ReplacePart** / **MapAt**:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = Nest[FlattenAt[#, {-1}] &, #, Depth[#] - 3] /. {} ->(##&[]) &;
f2 = Nest[ReplacePart[#, {-1, 0} -> Sequence] &, #, Depth[#] - 3] /. {} -> (##&[]) &;
f3 = Nest[MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, #, {-1}] &, #, Depth[#] - 3] /. {} -> (## &[]) &;
```

**Examples:**

```
acc1 = {{1, 2}, {{2, 3}, {{3, 4}, {{4, 5}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}}};
acc2 = {{1, 2}, {x, y}, {{2, 3, 4}, {{3, 4}, {{4, 5, 6}, {{5, 6}, {}, {u, v, w}}}}}};
acc3 = {{a, b, c}, {{2}, {{"a", 4}, {{4, 5}, {{5, 6}, {}}}}}};

f1 @ acc1
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}

```
f1 @ acc2
```

> {{1, 2}, {x, y}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6}, {u, v, w}}

```
f1 @ acc3
```

> {{a, b, c}, {2}, {"a", 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}

```
Equal @@ (# /@ {acc1, acc2, acc3} & /@ {f1, f2, f3})
```

> True