# How to efficiently Flatten nested lists while preserving select levels?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have lists of sets of variables, some in nested sub-lists:

```
t = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}}
```

I need to flatten this list in place but preserve the sets.  Flatten[t,1] does the opposite of what I want:

```
t = Flatten[t,1]
```

(*  {1, 2, 3, 4, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}   *)

The following code does what I want if there's only one level of flattening to do.  However, it requires a lot of copying, and I'm working with list of >10^5 elements, so I'd like to do this more efficiently if possible.

```
t = Reap[Do[If[Length[t[[i, 1]]] == 0, Sow[t[[i]]], Do[Sow[t[[i, j]]], {j, 1, Length[t[[i]]]}]], {i, 1, Length[t]}]][[2, 1]]

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Flatten this List with Inner List of Lists?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/how-can-i-flatten-this-list-with-inner-list-of-lists)

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Disturbingly I had no memory of answering the question to which you linked, though I seem to have nearly reproduced that answer here.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Heh, I happened upon your elegant `Level` solution only a few days ago so it was still fresh in my mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list elements are atomic [`Level`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) is fast and concise:

```
t = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};

Level[t, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

If you have something more complicated [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) can help:

```
t2 = {{a[1], a[2]}, {3, 4}, {{x[5], x[6]}, {7, 8, 9}}};

Cases[t2, {Except[_List], ___}, -2]
```

> ```
> {{a[1], a[2]}, {3, 4}, {x[5], x[6]}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

Comment: That seems to do *exactly* what I wanted, treat the lowest level lists as atomic.  I looked at the Level[] documentation after you posted this, but I don't understand what the {} in the levelspec is doing.  Should I make a separate Question of that?

Comment: @JerryGuern No, there is already a question about that; if you find it a useful topic please vote for the Question; it is unfairly down-voted IMO: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121 -- *edit* and if you feel my answer does not sufficiently address `{}` tell me and I shall try to improve it!

Comment: Done.  I upvoted that question and edited its title to be more specific.