# transforming lists to a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I convert the following lists to a list of lists?

```
{
 Flatten[{Range[2, 4, 1]}],    Flatten[{Range[6, 20, 1]}],  
 Flatten[{Range[26, 28, 1]}], Range[30, 31, 1], Range[35, 36, 1],
 Table[
 {
  Flatten[{Range[2 + n, 4 + n, 1]}],    
  Flatten[{Range[6 + n, 20 + n, 1]}],  
  Flatten[{Range[26 + n, 28 + n, 1]}], Range[30 + n, 31 + n, 1], 
  Range[35 + n, 36 + n, 1]
 }, {n, 36, 2304, 36}
   ]
 }
```

I want to transform the output generated by the above `Code` to something like, for example,

```
{{1,2,5}, {6,9,67,56},...,{4,45,67,5,7,7}}
```

I just want to get rid of unnecessary curly brackets generated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/how-can-i-flatten-this-list-with-inner-list-of-lists)

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the ranges? Perhaps there is a more elegant way to generate this, maybe by generating a full range and then eliminating unwanted entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Flatten[# + Range[{2, 6, 26, 30, 35}, {4, 20, 28, 31, 36}] & /@ Range[0, 2304, 36], 1]
```

gives the same output as  the method in your answer.

You can also use

```
Flatten[# + (Range @@@ {{2, 4}, {6, 20}, {26, 28}, {30, 31}, {35, 36}}) & /@ 
  Range[0, 2304, 36], 1] 

% == %%
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want, with fewer `Flatten` (Note that `Flatten[{Range[...]}]` is the same as `Range[...]`):

```
Table[
  {Range[2 + n, 4 + n, 1],
   Range[6 + n, 20 + n, 1],
   Range[26 + n, 28 + n, 1],
   Range[30 + n, 31 + n, 1],
   Range[35 + n, 36 + n, 1]},
  {n, {0} ~ Join ~ Range[36, 2304, 36]}
] ~ Flatten ~ 1
```

The first part of your lists, generated "by hand" in your code with the explicit `Range` calls, would have been generated by your `Table` expression for $n=0$, so I explicitly added that value of $n$ to the `Table` iterator, in addition to the other values that were already included there.

Comment: I wanted to create an index of numbers for aggregation of the selected rows and columns in a matrix. For example, {2,3,4} in the list of lists is used to sum up the elements in the associated rows and columns and maintains the resulting row/column as a new matrix element, while dropping the individual rows/columns summed up. This way matrix dimension is reduced by aggregation. Basically, I wanted to aggregate the selected rows/columns of a matrix. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the following does what I want, but I do not like it at all because there are many `Flatten` commends around. It looks ugly to me. Maybe someone can improve upon this.

```
Flatten[
 {
  {
   Flatten[{Range[2, 4, 1]}],    Flatten[{Range[6, 20,  1]}],  
Flatten[{Range[26, 28, 1]}], Range[30, 31, 1], Range[35, 36, 1]
 },
 Flatten[
 Table[
{
 Flatten[{Range[2 + n, 4 + n, 1]}],    
 Flatten[{Range[6 + n, 20 + n, 1]}],  
 Flatten[{Range[26 + n, 28 + n, 1]}], Range[30 + n, 31 + n, 1], 
 Range[35 + n, 36 + n, 1]
 }, {n, 36, 2304, 36}
 ], 1]
 }, 1]
```