# Sublist selection based on values present in another list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I want to select sublists from `list1` based on the values found in another list.

```
list1 = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}
list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

If the first element of a sublist in `list1` is present in `list2`, then it must be part of the output.

The desired output is:

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}

I tried:

```
Select[list1, #[[1]] == list2 &]
```

But then the output is empty.

Who has a suggestion?

Comment: `Select[list1, MemberQ[list2,#[[1]]]]` my brackets or ordering might be wrong...

Comment: Almost. `Select[list1, (MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] &)]`

Comment: Oops, knew I forgot something, thanks @LLlAMnYP

Comment: Great! It works -> thanks @LLlAMnYP

Comment: In the old days, we used to code like this: `list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
N0 = Length[list1];
M0 = Length[list2];
lst = {};
For[i = 1, i <= N0, i++,
  {
   candidate = list1[[i, 1]];
   found = False;
   For[j = 1, j <= M0, j++,
    {
     If[list2[[j]] == candidate,
      found = True;
      Break[]
      ]
     }
    ];
   If[found, AppendTo[lst, list1[[i]]]]
   }
  ];
lst`  which gives `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}` nowadays functional programming took all the fun away ;)

Comment: @Nasser, my eyes just started to bleed. Code can be funny :)

Comment: Super-fast method here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19398/363 with
output equivalent to `Cases[list1, {#, __}] & /@ list2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solutions

As mentioned in the comments you could use

```
Select[list1, list2~MemberQ~First[#] &]
```

Another way is to use patterns, i.e.

```
Cases[list1, {Alternatives @@ list2, __}]
```

or

```
Pick[list1, First@Transpose@list1, Alternatives @@ list2]
```

---

### How the pattern based work:

```
Alternatives @@ list2
(* Out:  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 *)
```

i.e. `{Alternatives @@ list2, __}` is the same as `{1 | 2 | 3 | 4,__}` which will match either `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` as the first element of the list. `__` matches one of several more elements, whatever they are. `Cases` tests each element in its first argument (`list1`) to see if it matches the pattern, then it selects those that match. You can test whether your pattern matches the rights elements like this:

```
MatchQ[#, {Alternatives @@ list2, __}] & /@ list1
(* Out: {True, True, True, False} *)
```

`Pick[list, sel, patt]` selects those elements in `list` for which the corresponding elements in `sel` match the pattern `patt`. `First@Transpose@list1` selects the first column from the matrix `list1`, this is the first element in each sublist. Therefore the pattern `patt` is just `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.

Answer (score 2):

A few additions to the list of methods in @Pickett's answer:

```
DeleteCases[#, Except@{Alternatives @@ #2, __}]&[list1, list2]

#[[Flatten@Position[#[[All, 1]], Alternatives @@ #2]]] &[list1, list2]
```

And an alternative form for `Select`:

```
Select[list1, Or @@ Function[{x}, #[[1]] == x] /@ list2 &]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Lookup`:**

Whenever "another" list interacts with the "main" list, it is a potential use case for `Lookup`.

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}
list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}

lut = GroupBy[list1, First]
```

> <|1 -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}}, 2 -> {{2, 3, 4, 5}},   5 -> {{5,
> 6, 7, 8}}|>

```
Lookup[lut, list2, Nothing] // Level[#, {-2}] &
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

A variant of @Syed's solution:

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
list2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

DeleteCases[{}] @ MapApply[Join] @ 
   Lookup[
      MapApply[{# -> {##}} &] @ list1, 
      list2, 
      {}]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}

`MapApply` was introduced in V 13.1

Answer (score 0):

Using `Insert` and `Partition`:

```
f[l1_, l2_] := Map[If[! FreeQ[#[[2]], #[[1, 1]]], #[[1]], Nothing] &, 
               Partition[Insert[#, l2, {# + 1} & /@ Ordering[#]], {2}]] &@l1
```

Testing the function `f`:

```
f[list1, list2]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}*)
```