# Quickly seeking an entry in a table

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a table:

```
codebook={{1, "BO4675365"}, {2, "4581X0DM7"}, {3, "BR8983933"}, {4,    "BR2057668"}, {5, "BN7431495"}, {6, "BG1120297"}, {7,    "ZN796880"}, {8, "BO9805678"}, {9, "BJ4669187"}, {10,    "BM0350801"}, {11, "ZQ6021518"}, {12, "BV671559"}, {13,    "BO3833387"}, {14, "BU6273025"}, {15, "BQ1964585"}, {16,    "BM7272362"}, {17, "ZP1747481"}, {18, "BZ314326"}, {19,    "ZM5972504"}, {20, "UV8801572"}}
```

To "read" the code, I search for the alphanumeric entry, and read the corresponding value

```
Select[codebook, #[[2]] == "4581X0DM7" &] // AbsoluteTiming
```

which gives (for a table with 7209 entries),

> {0.021373, {{2, "4581X0DM7"}}}

So to read the entry number, I use,

```
Select[codebook, #[[2]] == "4581X0DM7" &][[1, 1]]
```

which gives

> 2

Is there a faster way of picking the right entry? Running this millions of times may be trouble. Basically I'm looking for the fastest way to read from a table and get a code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create two `Associations`s, one for picking by number and the other for queries by code. For large tables `Associations`s will be considerably faster than `Select`.

**1. By number**

```
enum = First /@ GroupBy[First -> Last] @ codebook

Lookup[enum, 6, {}]
```

"BG1120297"

```
Lookup[enum, {6, 7, -1}, {}]
```

{"BG1120297", "ZN796880", {}}

```
enum[6]
```

"BG1120297"

**2. By code**

```
code = First /@ GroupBy[Last -> First] @ codebook;

Lookup[code, "ZP1747481", {}]
```

17

```
code["ZP1747481"]
```

17

**3. KeyTake**

If you want to see both entries:

```
KeyTake[{"BO4675365", "BO9805678"}] @ code
```

<|"BO4675365" -> 1, "BO9805678" -> 8|>

Convert to `List`:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ KeyTake[{"BO4675365", "BO9805678"}] @ code
```

{{"BO4675365", 1}, {"BO9805678", 8}}

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [2013 answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19398/363) by Mr.Wizard.

It is fast because it only traverses the codebook once (and doesn't use `Alternatives` which would be quite slow).

```
getSubset[input_List, sub_List] := Module[{test},
  (test@# = True) &~Scan~sub;
  Apply[Sequence,
    Reap[Cases[input, x : {_, y_?test} :> x~Sow~y], sub][[2]], {2}]] 

alphanums = {"BM0350801", "NOTINLIST", "BR2057668"};

found = getSubset[codebook, alphanums]
```

> {{{10, "BM0350801"}}, {}, {{4, "BR2057668"}}}

```
First /@ Catenate[found]
```

> {10, 4}

Entries not found can be identified

```
Extract[alphanums, Position[found, {}]]
```

> {"NOTINLIST"}

Comment: Maybe not relevant here, but pattern-free Alternatives were sped up in version 13.3.